# Tcl catch to display procedure name

Tags: exception, tcl, try-catch

Lets say I have multiple procedure calls in one `catch` block.

```
catch {
    proc1
    proc2
    proc3
} errMsg
```

Is there a way to display which of those procedures threw an exception, after catching it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the `errorInfo` global variable, you will see a stack trace that contains the information you want. You can also get that information by adding an extra variable argument  to the `catch` call after `errMsg`, which will have a dictionary written to it that includes the error info trace as well as other things (e.g., the computer-readable exception code).

---

[EDIT]: In Tcl 8.6, the exception option dictionary has an element `-errorstack` that contains a description of what is being called. Here's an interactive session that shows this:

```
% proc foo {x} {error $x} 
% proc bar c {catch {puts a;foo $c} a b;return $b}
% bar d
a
-code 1 -level 0 -errorstack {INNER {returnImm d {}} CALL {foo d} CALL {bar d}} -errorcode NONE -errorinfo {d
    while executing
"error $x"
    (procedure "foo" line 1)
    invoked from within
"foo $c"} -errorline 1
```

The error stack has pairs of elements for various things, but the key ones are the `CALL` type ones, where the second element of each pair is the list of arguments that were used to actually do the call. It might be possible to make use of this to obtain the name. (The `INNER` type refers to the execution state of the Tcl bytecode engine, and I don't know if there are any other types about.)

Comment: I tried to add an extra variable after `errMsg`. It does catch the name of the procedure under `-errorinfo` key, but it is part of the error message string. That means I will need to parse the string to get the name. I thought there could be a cleaner way to get it.

Comment: @Mr.SrJenea _Perhaps_ there are. The errorstack info in 8.6 might be helpful. Or maybe not; I'm not at all sure what the best way of parsing it to determine where in the list to look is.

Comment: My requirements are limited to version 8.5. I guess I will just either have multiple `catch` blocks, or use `regexp` to extract the procedure name. Thanks